# Return a value from an observable inside a method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

This seems to be a very simple problem but I can't find a single solution about this (my research might be wrong).

I'm calling a method where I try to subscribe to an Observable and return a value from it.

Something like that :

```
myMethod(): string {
   return this.towns$.subscribe(towns => 
      towns.map(town => {
            if (town.id === 5) return town.name;
      })
   );
}
```

Maybe this can't / shouldn't be done.

I tried something like this too but it doesn't work since it isn't synchronous :

```
myMethod(): string {
   let name = '';
   this.towns$.subscribe(towns => 
      towns.map(town => {
            if (town.id === 5) name = town.name;
      })
   );
   return name;
}
```

Comment: town$ is my Observable<Town[]>. I get it from my `ngOnInit()` with :
`this.towns$ = this.facade.towns$`

Comment: You cannot return anything from subscribe. Why not subscribe where you actually need the value?

Comment: Move your Subscribe() into the ngOnInit(), then set an internal property, myVal to town.name when the condition is met. The function myMethod() should just return your component's myVal property, which is assigned AFTER the observable returns values from the subscription. If your observable doesn't return by the time you retrieve the result from myMethod() then the myVal value will be blank.

Comment: @AndrewHalil I understand, but what if my value town.id where I'm doing my `if` is changing from the user? it won't be done again in the `ngOnInit`, right ?

Comment: Within ngOnInit() the Subscribe() will call your backend data service once during the component creation. For backend data changes to be pushed to the Angular client, that could be done using websockets, SignalR, NgRx, or periodically pull data using background polling using RxJS. If real-time data is not a requirement, then subscribing from one location is sufficient. Moving the subscribe to a method like you suggested raises the issue of how you would keep track of each subscription created and dispose them later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables are collections that emit items *over time*. So you can't write code as you have shown.

Try instead something like this:

```
townName$ = this.towns$.pipe(
      map(towns => towns.map(town => {
            if (town.id === 5) return town.name;
            return '';
      }))
   );
}
```

The `$` suffix implies it's an Observable. It will then emit the town name when subscribed to in the component.

If the component subscribes to `townName$`, RxJS will automatically subscribe to `this.towns$`. The pipe allows you to take the value emitted from `this.towns$` and pipe it through a set of operations.

If you are interested in learning more about how Observables work, check out the first talk from this user group meeting (only 30 minutes of your time!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSsch65n8Yw

**UPDATE**
To react to changes in the townId, you can use code like this:

```
  // Define an action stream
  private selectionChangedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  selectionChanged$ = this.selectionChangedSubject.asObservable();

  // Use combineLatest to work with both streams
  townName$ = combineLatest([this.towns$, this.selectionChanged$]).pipe(
    map(([towns, townId]) => {
      const town = towns.find(town => town.id === townId);
      return town?.name;
    })
  );

  // Emit the id into the action stream
  // when the action occurs
  onSelectionChanged(townId: number): void {
    this.selectionChangedSubject.next(townId);
  }
```

The action stream manages the town selection action and emits the townId each time the user picks a different town.

The combineLatest allows us to work with both the `towns$` stream (with all towns) and the `selectionChanged$` action stream.

For a more detailed discussion of how this works, see the above referenced video.

I have a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-react-to-action-deborahk

Dochvam nuv bey'

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Same as a comment above, but what if my value town.id where I'm doing my `if` is changing from the user? it will not change on the front view

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out the video? It shows how to modify this code to react to user actions, such as selecting a different town.id.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

It's the same as having an async call in a method, where you will never be able to return the value directly without marking the method as async, and thus returning a Promise.